# jquery: Summing values after dynamic delete of content gets NaN

Tags: javascript, jquery, nan

here is my js:

```
function sumAllFields() {
    var priceSum = 0;
    $(".price").each(function () {
        var o = $(this).parent().parent().index();
        priceSum += Number($("#area" + o).text()) * $("#price" + o).val();
    })
    $("#sumPrice, #printSumPrice").html(priceSum.toFixed(2));
}
```

And here is relevant html:

```
<tbody id="tableBody">
<tr class="tableRow" id="tableRow0"> 
    <td><input class="idNumber" id="idNumber0" type="number"></td>
    <td><input class="description" id="description0" type="text"></td>
    <td class="dimA" id="dimA0">520</td>
    <td class="dimB" id="dimB0">785</td>
    <td><input class="pcs" id="pcs0" type="number"></td>
    <td class="area" id="area0">2.46</td>
    <td><input class="price" id="price0" type="number"></td>
    <td class="noprint"><span class="closed">×</span></td>                         
</tr>

<!-- and a few more in between... -->

<tr class="tableRow" id="tableRow8">
    <td><input class="idNumber" id="idNumber8" type="number"></td>
    <td><input class="description" id="description8" type="text"></td>
    <td class="dimA" id="dimA8">510</td>
    <td class="dimB" id="dimB8">785</td>
    <td><input class="pcs" id="pcs8" type="number"></td>
    <td class="area" id="area8">0.80</td>
    <td><input class="price" id="price8" type="number"></td>
    <td class="noprint"><span class="closed">×</span></td>                         
</tr>
</tbody>
```

What I am trying to do is to automatically sum all `.price` fields after one `<tr>` is dynamically deleted, and all I get is NaN. Before I delete any row, I get a nice number, but after I delete any rows, I get NaN.

Comment: Does it fix your issue: `priceSum += Number($("#area" + o).text()) * $("#price" + o).val() || 0;` ?!

Comment: Partly, I don't get NaNs anymore, but I don't get the right sum either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because of the logic you have used to find the sibling `price/area` element. Assume you have added 4 items, so you have elements like `area0/area1/area2/area3`. Now you are deleting row 2 so the element `area1` is no longer present then in your each loop in the second iteration `o` becomes 1 then it tries to find element `#area1` but there is no such element which results in `Number($("#area" + o).text())` returning `NaN`.

Try

```
function sumAllFields() {
    var priceSum = 0;
    $(".price").each(function () {
        var $tr = $(this).closest('tr');
        priceSum += (+$tr.find(".area").text() * +this.value) || 0;
    })
    $("#sumPrice, #printSumPrice").html(priceSum.toFixed(2));
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/y6fbn40x/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Lets iterate table rows directly:

```
function sumAllFields() {
  var priceSum = 0;
  $('.tableRow').each(function () {
    var row = $(this);
    priceSum += (parseFloat(row.find('.area').text())
      * parseFloat(row.find('.price').val())) || 0;
  })
  $('#sumPrice, #printSumPrice').html(priceSum.toFixed(2));
}
```